# Find the partial fraction for: $\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2(x-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I want to find the partial fraction of: $$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2(x-1)}$$
Although I want this expressed through the format of finding the complex number that goes into $x$ so that I can get this equation in the form:
$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2(x-1)}-\frac{Ax+b}{f(x)}$$
Where $f(x)$ represents the value of the denominator left from the original equation after finding the complex root.

I want to repeat this until I find the partial fractions mainly so that I have enough practice in understanding partial fractions through this method.

My approach:

I know that $(x^2+1)$ has a complex number given by: $x^2+1 = 0 \implies x = \sqrt{-1}$ Therefore $x = \pm i$

Plugging this into the equation above, I should get:
$$\frac{A(\pm i )+b}{(\pm i -1)}$$
Where $Ax+b = 1$

Although I'm unsure on how to proceed from here and would greatly appreciate assistance from mathematics community.

Answer (score 2):

The decomposition into partial fractions has the form
$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2(x-1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}+ \frac{Dx+E}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
To obtain $A$, multiply both sides by $x-1$ and set $x=1$.

For $D$ and $E$, multiply by $(x^2+1)^2$ and set $x=i$.

Last, for $B$, multiply by $x$ and let $x\to\infty$. For $C$, you can set $x$ to any particular value which is not a pole of the fraction, e.g. $x=0$.

Comment: for $Dx+E$ I get $\frac{1}{i-1}$ surely this can be simplified further? Or am I missing the picture here. As for the solution to $Bx+C$ I'm unaware on how to proceed when we multiply by $x$, do I factor out the $x$ to get $\frac{x(Bx+C)}{x^2+1}$ if $x \to \infty$ for $Bx$ then that goes off to zero. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: @Stackcans: For $Dx+E$, you write $\frac 1{i-1}$ in the form $x+iy$ and identify the real parts and the imaginary parts. For $x\to \infty$, you calculate the limits of each side, e.g., $\frac{x(Bx+C)}{x^2+1}\to B$.

Comment: This is still rather complex for me. I'll have to do more practice on partial fractions and complex numbers. Though I'll be sure to update my response until then